# Fabric.js - get oCoords object every 400ms while animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

in Fabric.js, is it possible to get coordinates of a shape as it is being animated? I am using the object defined here to get the shapes coordinates:

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#oCoords

Here is an example:

http://fabricjs.com/static_canvas/

[image: Visual Example]

When I get these objects points in my code it only gets the points at the start and end of the animate, I am trying to collect the oCoords data every 400ms of the shape being animated:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   attrSniperBrX = Math.round(snipers[index].oCoords.br.x); 
   attrSniperBrY = Math.round(snipers[index].oCoords.br.y); 
   heatMapAdd(attrSniperBrX, attrSniperBrY);

   console.log(attrSniperBrX, attrSniperBrY);
 }, 400);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually call the `setCoords()` method.
It is not called automatically on animation because of performance reason on main thread. On setInterval you should have no problems.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   /* guessing that sniper array contains fabricjs objects */
   snipers[index].setCoords();
   attrSniperBrX = Math.round(snipers[index].oCoords.br.x); 
   attrSniperBrY = Math.round(snipers[index].oCoords.br.y); 
   heatMapAdd(attrSniperBrX, attrSniperBrY);

   console.log(attrSniperBrX, attrSniperBrY);
 }, 400);
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem.